# How to disable the row selection after specific no of counts in UItableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I wanted to disable the UITableView cell selection after selecting 10 rows in multiselect UITableView,
After deselecting some rows again user will able to select the UITableView cell.

Can anybody please suggest me, how can i do this?

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement `willSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath:`

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  if (tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows.count < YourMaxRowSelectedCount) {
    return indexPath;
  } else {
    return nil;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `indexPathsForSelectedRows` returns an `NSArray` object of index paths of all the selected rows of the table view. You can check count of that to compare to your required number of selected rows and act accordingly.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick response, but I have used above answer and its working.